# How to set up Ubuntu 14.04 as a gateway using 1 NIC with 2 IP addresses on different subnets?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, router, gateway

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with one NIC. The MAC address on this NIC is assigned (by the gateway) one IP (X.X.X.100) in one subnet (X.X.X.0/24), with the gateway being in the same subnet (X.X.X.1), and an IP range from a completely different subnet (Y.Y.Y.0/28).

I've set up the server with both X.X.X.100 and Y.Y.Y.1 on the same interface (eth0), and the server can contact and be contacted by the rest of the Internet

I have some virtual machines that use the IP addresses from the second subnet. They can contact the host on both its IP addresses, but nothing else. I assume they must use the host's second IP address Y.Y.Y.1 as a gateway, but how do I set up the host so that all requests to or from the Y.Y.Y.0/28 subnet are routed via the gateway X.X.X.1?

As far as I know, I cannot simply expand the netmask, as this could lead to not being able to contact other servers on the net.

Here's the server's `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto  eth0

iface eth0 inet static
  address   X.X.X.100
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   X.X.X.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

iface eth0 inet static
  address   Y.Y.Y.1
  netmask   255.255.255.240
```

In `/etc/sysctl.conf` I have enabled this line:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

The VMs use Y.Y.Y.n (where n>1) as IP address and Y.Y.Y.1 as gateway.

### UPDATE:

I think the VMs can't find the MAC address of the ISP's gateway X.X.X.1:

```
$ arp -an
? (Y.Y.Y.1) at c8:60:00:5e:bd:e0 [ether] on eth0
? (X.X.X.1) at <incomplete> on eth0
```

However strangely, they can sometimes...

```
$ arp -an
? (X.X.X.1) at c8:60:00:5e:bd:e0 [ether] on eth0
? (Y.Y.Y.1) at cc:e1:7f:07:e0:af [ether] on eth0
```

When this happens everything actually works! I can access the Internet from the VMs and access them from the internet using their Y.Y.Y.n address. But it doesn't work all the time - it "forgets" the MAC address of Y.Y.Y.1, and becomes inaccessible.

I'm actually surprised it lists Y.Y.Y.1 in the arp list at all - I thought that was only for devices in the same subnet. My goal was to make them just use the host as gateway address (Y.Y.Y.1) instead and avoid the problem by letting the host to all the communication on X.X.X.0/24.

Is my configuration a sensible one?

Are anyone else using this configuration?

What possible reasons could there be for the weird "forgetfulness"?